# Eager load an association of an eager loaded association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I begin with model A, eager_load model B and want to load model C (which is only associated with model B), how do I do this and avoid N+1 queries?

ModelA.eager_load([:modelB, :modelC]) doesn't work since ModelA has no association with ModelC.

Comment: Try to use `modelB: :modelC` instead of `[:modelB, :modelC]`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution as posted by @maxd - .eager_load(modelB: :modelC).